# Apache rewrite - Read a header from incoming requests and allow only if the header value is part of HTTP HOST

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I have a scenario below that I am having trouble with. I am trying to Read a header from incoming requests and allow only if the header value is part of HTTP HOST

- A request header called Auth_type is set on every request. The value of the header is in the following format:  Ex "app01dev" or "app01prd"  or “app02prd”.
- Example hostname of the applications is in the following format: Ex: “app01-host-site.com” or “app02-host-site.com”
- Write a mod rewrite rule to allow transactions only if first 5 characters of the header value is part of HTTP host name.  In other words, If the HTTP HOST doesn’t contain the first 5 characters of header value anywhere with in its text, just deny. In this scenario, If the HTTP Host is app01-host-site.com and the header is app02prd, then request should be denied. Allow should only be if the header value is “app01dev” or “app01prd”

I tried the below and I think I am having a syntax issue. Any help is much appreciated!

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^*app01*
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404,L]
```